# can't step into java source code. "step into" somehow act like "step over"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to studying how a method in java String class works, so I created some customised code that calls that String class method.

As you can see, I have set a break point in my own code and I have set another break point in the java String class source code.

While I'm in debug mode and is on line 7 of my code, I pressed `step into`.

However, rather than stepping into the String class method `indexOf`, eclipse instead moved onto line 8 of my code.

Why is this happening? how can I step into the java string method source code?

[image]

```
public class TestingIndexOfMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String stringToBeSearchedThrough = "hello world";
        final String substringToLookFor = "ll";
        int a = stringToBeSearchedThrough.indexOf(substringToLookFor, 0);
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I have already check to see, if "use step filter" is activated before asking this question on SO, and it is not activated. So I dont think "use step filter" is the problem here.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

`step into` works fine with methods I defined myself

Comment: Do you have the source?  If the vendor did not supply the source, how would you step into the source?

Comment: @cup on the right hand side of the attached pic, is the source code of java string class.

Comment: `java.lang.String` class implements this method and eclipse shows its souce code. I tried `Step into` in eclipse and it works fine

Comment: @JaySmith yeah, it seems either i'm very unlucky or very stupid. I searched through stackoverflow, this problem does seem to occur very infrequent

Comment: Press `Run` tab and select `Step into` option

Comment: @JaySmith I did, but doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably there is a step filter which instructs the debugger to skip certain classes.

In the preferences dialog (menu Window -> Preferences) check the step filtering settings.

Either deactivate `Use Step Fitlers` which deactivates all step filters or deactivate the filter for the classes `java.*` only.

[image: Eclipse step filtering]

**edit** Another reason might be that your project is using a JRE instead of a JDK for the execution. Find below an example using a Java 8 JRE respective a Java 8 JDK.

project build path using a **JRE** (pay attention to `jre1.8.0_112`)
[image: project runtime JRE]

project build path using a **JDK** (pay attention to `JavaSE-1.8`)
[image: project runtime JDK]

**edit 2** To determine the used Java runtime library add following statement in your code and run it in debug mode.

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of(System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path")
            .split(File.pathSeparator))
            .filter(s -> s.endsWith("rt.jar"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    ...
```

Comment: before asking on SO, I have already check if "use step filter" is activated, and it is not, so I dont think "use step filter" is the problem here. But still, thanks for helping out!!

Comment: @CaptainAmerica I added another possible reason.

Comment: hi SubOptimal, I have checked my eclipse IDE setting, the project has JDK, not JRE, in its build path, so I dont think this is the problem. Really appreciate you helping out, can't say enough thank you!

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Could you please add the code to get the used runtime library. Maybe this will bring some light into it.

Comment: hi SubOptimal, I can't say enough thank you for your help and patience!! After I have used your suggested code in the "edit 2", I found out that I was indeed using JRE instead of JDK. People like you are the reason why I love StackOverflow so much. Its full of generous people willing to give a helping hand. Thanks again!!

Comment: @CaptainAmerica You're very welcome. I try to give something back, for what I get from SO. ;-)